# Svelte Kit failed to resolve import "svelte-persistent-store/dist/local"

Tags: npm, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I installed the `svelte-persistent-store` library, and got error while importing `writable` from `svelte-persistent-store/dist/local`

`theme.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts" context="module">
  import { setContext } from 'svelte'
  import { writable as persist } from 'svelte-persistent-store/dist/local'
  import type { Writable } from 'svelte/store'

  export type Theme = 'light' | 'dark'
  export type ThemeContext = Writable<Theme>

  const theme = 'light'

  setContext('theme', persist('theme', theme))
</script>

<slot />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [alternative usage](https://github.com/andsala/svelte-persistent-store#usage) works correctly in SvelteKit:

```js
// ❌ fails to resolve
// import { writable, readable, derived } from 'svelte-persistent-store/dist/local';

// ✅
import { local } from 'svelte-persistent-store';
const { writable, readable, derived } = local;
```